# Save manage meta data value using REST API in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have to update taxonomy field data using REST API in SharePoint 2013. How to do that? I am using below code to update data. But how to update taxonomy field value?

```
$.ajax({
                url: data.d.results[0].__metadata.uri,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.PagesItem' },
                    "Module": $('[id$=txtModule0_ctl00_TextField]').val(),
                    "Story" :$('[id$=Story_ctl00_BooleanField]').is(':checked'),
                    "Image":{ Url: $('[id$=Image_ctl00_UrlFieldUrl]').val(), Description: "" },
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                    "If-Match": data.d.results[0].__metadata.etag
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('data saved');
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: You have a taxonomy field which is attached to a term set. From your code I am assuming that its a page field on a page layout, and you must be having a taxonomy picker control on the page. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes you are correct. In java script I got the term set value but using rest Api i am not able to update the value.

Comment: If its a site column on page layout, and you want to save a page. I believe field data are stored with out any code. `<PageFieldTaxonomyFieldControl:TaxonomyFieldControl ID="TaxonomyFieldControl1" FieldName="YourFieldName" runat="server"></PageFieldTaxonomyFieldControl:TaxonomyFieldControl>` . My question would be are you trying to use page field values and using it to store some where else?

Comment: Yes I know that. But I have a requirement that I have to store data using code base programmatically. How to do that using Rest Api?

Comment: I have update taxonomy field values just by assigning TERM ID, My code was JSOM. But I believe you can try passing term id with REST as well.

Answer (score 4):

It depends whether taxonomy field is *multi* or *single* valued.

In case of *single-valued taxonomy field*, the following example demonstrates how to update its value:

```
function executeJson(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers = headers || {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }      
    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if (typeof payload != 'undefined') {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}

function updateListItem(webUrl, listTitle,itemId, itemPayload) {
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle +  "')/items(" + itemId + ")";
    var headers = {};
    headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
    headers["If-Match"] = "*";
    return executeJson(endpointUrl,'POST',headers,itemPayload);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var listTitle = 'Contacts';
var itemId = 1;
var taxFieldName = 'TaxCountry';  //<-tax field name
var itemPayload = {
             '__metadata' : {'type': 'SP.Data.ContactsListItem'},
             taxFieldName : {
                 '__metadata' : {'type': 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue'},
                 'Label': 'Norway',  //<-set term label here
                 'TermGuid':'aaa54679-ce8a-44c2-ba29-0df41ee7deca',  //<- set term guid here 
                 'WssId': -1
              }
          };   



updateListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,itemPayload)
   .done(function(){
       console.log('Tax field valued has been updated');
   })
   .fail(function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   });
```

Comment: I am following your post but I am not able to make this code working. I am not getting any error, code succeed but the field value does not updated.