# Saving custom input values to sharepoint metadata columns

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list called Employees , i created a custom form for saving the data. The custom form holds five fields. Which are created using normal html input tags

1. Name: (input type = text)
2. ID: (input type= number)
3. Country:(input type = select which consist of options they are dynamically 
            added from metadata)
4. State: (input type = select which consist of options they are dynamically added based on the selection of Country field)
5. ContactNo: (input type = number)
6. Submit: (input type = button)

Columns in Employee Details

1. Name    (type = string)
2. Id      (type = number)
3. Country (type = managed metadata having Country Metdata)
4. State   (type = managed metadata having State Metadata)
5. ContactNo (type = number)

**Meta Data Management Structure**

```
EmployeesDetails(Term Set)
      Country(Term)
          India(Term)
          US(Term)
      State(Term)
          India(Term)
             New Delhi(Term)
             Karnataka(Term)
          US(Term)
             NewYork(Term)
             LosAngels(Term)
```

So when we are saving the record it should save to the corresponding columns. I am able to list state based on the selection of country from managed meta data. How can i save the record to the corresponding columns of state and country which are managed meta data columns using javascript?

Many regards

Answer (score 0):

you may try the below function to update the metadata fields

```
 function ExecUpdate(endpointUrl, itemTerm) {
        var headers = {};
        headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
        headers["If-Match"] = "*";

        headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
        var method = 'POST';
        var ajaxOptions =
        {
            url: url,
            type: method,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: headers
        };
        if (typeof itemterm != 'undefined') {
            ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(itemTerm);
        }
        return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    }
```

and you can set the variables as below

```
    var listName = 'list name';  //set list name
    var itemId = 1; //set item id
    var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")";
    var fieldName = 'field name';  // field name
    var itemTerm = {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ContactsListItem' },
        fieldName: {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue' },
            'Label': 'set term label',  //set term label 
            'TermGuid': '73ggdtes-8weg-6dsg-f982-9djksh6dvd34',  //set term guid 
            'WssId': -1
        }
    };
    ExecUpdate(endpointUrl, itemTerm)
```

you may also check a similar post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144085/save-manage-meta-data-value-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: I tried the code and the post that you have shared it doesn't seems to work.  I have updated my question , i hope it can give you a better understanding Thanks in advance..